# How can i print a message when a home page is loaded using widget in odoo10?

Tags: javascript, odoo-10

I'm a beginner and i was writing java script code on odoo10.0. I referred codes that written previous versions. So, I want to print 'Nidhin, your pet store home page loaded' when my home page is loaded.

```
 In mypetstore/static/src/js/my_pet_store.js:
```

mypetstore is my module name .

```
odoo.define('mypetstore.my_pet_store', function (require) {
"use strict";
var Class = require('web.Class');
var Widget = require('web.Widget');
var core = require('web.core');
var utils = require('web.utils');

var _t = core._t;
var _lt = core._lt;
var QWeb = core.qweb;
console.log("Nidhin");
HomePage = Widget.extend({
    start: function() {
        console.log("Nidhin, your pet store home page loaded");
    },
});
core.view_registry.add('my_pet_store', HomePage);
});
```

In mypetstore/views/my_pet_store.xml

```
<template id="assets_backend" name="petstore" 
inherit_id="web.assets_backend">
    <xpath expr="." position="inside">
        <script type="text/javascript" 
  src="/mypetstore/static/src/js/my_pet_store.js"></script>
    </xpath>
</template> 

 <record id="action_home_page_my_petstore" model="ir.actions.client">
    <field name="name">Pet Store Home</field>
    <field name="tag">my_pet_store</field>
</record>
```

In menu:

```
<menuitem id="home_page_my_petstore_menu" 
        name="Home Page"
        parent="my_petstore_menu"
        action="action_home_page_my_petstore"/>
```

In custom_addons/mypetstore/manifest.py:

'depends': [
         'web',
    ],
    'data': [
    'views/my_pet_store.xml',
    'views/menu.xml',
     ],
      'demo': [
      ],

Expected behavior:

I have seen same code in openerp(previous version):

```
 openerp.oepetstore = function(instance, local) {
  var _t = instance.web._t,
  _lt = instance.web._lt;
  var QWeb = instance.web.qweb;

  local.HomePage = instance.Widget.extend({
     start: function() {
     console.log("pet store home page loaded");
    },
 });

 instance.web.client_actions.add('petstore.homepage', 
 'instance.oepetstore.HomePage');
 }
```

So, I want to print 'Nidhin, your pet store home page loaded' when my home page is loaded.

Comment: I also asked the similar question today... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45351011/odoo10-javascript-widget-action-not-working-clientwidget-is-not-a-function     But I must say, yours is pretty straightforward. So no answer?

Comment: @user568021 I got the answer

Comment: So what was your solution?

Comment: @user568021 I have given the answer below. Please check it.

Answer (score 0):

i got the output when i did this:
in .js file:

```
    odoo.define('zbtoken.hellojs', function (require) {
      "use strict";

    var Widget = require('web.Widget');
    var core = require('web.core');
    var utils = require('web.utils');
    var HomePage = Widget.extend({
        template: "HelloJS",
    start: function() {
        console.log("Hello JS");
        },
    });

    core.action_registry.add('HelloJS', HomePage);
    }); 

   In .xml file :

    <?xml version="1.0"  encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <templates xml:space="preserve">
    <t t-name="HelloJS">
      <div> </div>
     </t>  
    </templates>

   In .xml view file:
   You have to specify your js file in view's xml file like:

     <data>   
    <template id="assets_backend" name="petstore" 
              inherit_id="web.assets_backend">
        <xpath expr="." position="inside">
         <script type="text/javascript" src="your js file path">
         </script>
        </xpath>
   </template>
   <record id="map_id" model="ir.actions.client">
        <field name="name">HelloJS</field>
        <field name="tag">HelloJS</field>
    </record>
    </data>  

     in _maniifest_.py
      'data': [ 
               'views/your_xml_file', 
       ],
      'demo': [
       ],
      'qweb': ['static/src/xml/your_xml_file'],
```

Call the id 'map_id' in menu, then you will get print 'Hello JS' in console. Sorry for the late reply.

Comment: I copy-pasted your code and set the action to the menu item and again I got the Could not find client action HelloJS error.. I'm cursed :(

Comment: @user568021 I have added some more line and that you need to check in your code. You have to specify your js file in view's xml file, and you have to specify your xml file in qweb in _manifest_.py file. And please share your code if your getting errors.

Comment: Ok.. I think I've got it now! Thank you sooo much. You deserve the bounty from my question!