# Odoo10 Javascript Widget action not working: ClientWidget is not a function

Tags: javascript, widget, odoo-10

I'm still learning how to properly add your own javascript code. I'm trying to add my own stuff into Odoo backend.

I was carefully reading "Building Interface Extensions" guide (https://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/howtos/web.html), but it is ether badly inaccurate or completely outdated.

After looking at Odoo official modules like Account, Project, CRM I've coded something like this:

```
odoo.define('rhp.main', function (require) {
"use strict";

var core = require('web.core');
var _t = core._t;
var _lt = core._lt;
var Widget = require('web.Widget');
var QWeb = core.qweb;

var Explorer = Widget.extend({
    init: function(parent, options) {
        console.log('Explorer inited');
    },
    start: function() {
        console.log('Explorer started');
    },
});

/* NONE OF THESE WORK OK */
//core.view_registry.add('exploreraction', Explorer);
//core.action_registry.add('exploreraction', function() { return new Explorer(); });
core.action_registry.add('exploreraction', 'rhp.main.Explorer');
//odoo.client_actions.add('exploreraction', Explorer);

/* "Main loaded" is successfully printed in console */
console.log("Main loaded");

return {
    Explorer: Explorer,
};

});
```

My module xml data:

```
<record id="explorer_action" model="ir.actions.client">
    <field name="name">Document Explorer</field>
    <field name="tag">exploreraction</field>
    <field name="target">main</field>
</record>

<menuitem name="Documents" id="main_docs" />
<menuitem name="Document Explorer" id="rhp_explorer" parent="rhp.main_docs" action="rhp.explorer_action"/>
```

This is my latest code and when I click the menu item nothing happens and I get this popup error:

```
TypeError: ClientWidget is not a function
```

Traceback pasted here https://pastebin.com/QLCaLwHC

=========================================

**EDIT:**

I added the template, like in Vishal Khichadiya's example:

```
<t t-name="exploreraction" >
    <div id="exploreraction_div">
        test
    </div>
</t>
```

Action is now added this way:

```
core.action_registry.add('exploreraction', Explorer);
```

Now when I navigate to my menu item I'm now getting this error:

```
TypeError: this.__getterSetterInternalMap is undefined
```

New traceback here: https://pastebin.com/phrqXFkz

Comment: I am not getting what exactly you want?

Comment: @VikiChavada I want to create a javascript file-browser-like interface and use it in Odoo backend. But basically my problem is that the official documentation (petstore) that I referenced is totally false, as far as I've followed.

Comment: Anyway, I would be happy to get something like this OpenERP7 view/widget/orwhatever in Odoo10. See image: https://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/_images/qweb.png

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm also new to Odoo and JS, and I have tried something and that is given below:

```
    In your /static/src/js/your_.js file, add the code:

    odoo.define('zbtoken.map', function (require) {
        "use strict";

    var Widget = require('web.Widget');
    var core = require('web.core');
    var utils = require('web.utils');


    var HomePage = Widget.extend({
       template: "HelloJS",

       init: function(parent) {
            this._super(parent);
            console.log("Hello JS, I'm inside of init.");
       },


    start: function() {
            console.log("Hello JS, I'm inside of start.");
     },
   });

   core.action_registry.add('HelloJS', HomePage);

   return HomePage;
   });
```

In your /static/src/xml/your_.xml file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"  encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <templates xml:space="preserve">
       <t t-name="HelloJS">
          <div> </div>
       </t>
    </templates>
```

In your /views/your_.xml file:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <odoo>
      <data>

    <template id="assets_backend" name="petstore" 
        inherit_id="web.assets_backend">
        <xpath expr="." position="inside">
            <script type="text/javascript"         
            src="/your_module_name/static/src/js/your_js_file.js">
            </script>
        </xpath>
    </template> 

    <record id="hellojs_id" model="ir.actions.client">
        <field name="name">HelloJS</field>
        <field name="tag">HelloJS</field>
    </record>
     <menuitem id="hellojs_menu" 
            name="HelloJS" 
            action="hellojs_id"/>
     </data>
     </odoo>
```

In *manifest*.py:

```
     'data': [ 
     'views/your_.xml file',  
      ],

     'qweb': ['static/src/xml/your_.xml file'],
```

It will work. Please try it.

Comment: Sorry.. you'll have to wait 23 hours for the bounty. Thanks again, sir!

Comment: @user568021 I have added a solution for this too https://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/_images/qweb.png. Please have a look. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to design a Template by your self.

You'll find reference code in odoo it self for create template.

add you template file in manifest file as 'qweb': ["static/src/xml/my_template.xml"]

```
odoo.define('rhp.main', function (require) {
"use strict";

var core = require('web.core');
var _t = core._t;
var _lt = core._lt;
var Widget = require('web.Widget');
var QWeb = core.qweb;

var Explorer = Widget.extend({
    init: function(parent, options) {
        console.log('Explorer inited');
    },
    start: function() {
        console.log('Explorer started');
    },
});
//exploreraction is must be your template name        
core.action_registry.add('exploreraction', Explorer);

return Explorer;


});
```

Examplea Template code:

```
<t t-name="exploreraction" >
    <div id="my_temp_id">
    <div class="ex_button">
        <div class="cancle_btn">
            <button class="btn btn-danger">Cancle</button>
        </div>
        <div class="Add_btn">
            <button class="btn btn-success">Add </button>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</t>
```

create assets_backend.xml with your other xml files.

/view/assets_backend.xml
--> Here you need to add javasscript file path.

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
 <odoo>
   <data>
    <template id="assets_backend" inherit_id="web.assets_backend">
        <xpath expr="script[last()]" position="after">

            <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/src/js/rhp_main.js"></script>
        </xpath>
    </template>
    <template id="assets_common" inherit_id="web.assets_common">
        <xpath expr="script[last()]" position="after">

        </xpath>
    </template>
  </data>
 </odoo>
```

Comment: I don't understand your answer. Can you provide some reference?

Comment: Which part you don't understand? Do I need to provide you some reference code?

Comment: "Reference" is like a source of the information you provide. Also you are mentioning some 'template' and that it should be assigned when adding the action, but you don't show this in your code. If I copy-paste your code, it will still fail.. :(

Comment: You can take reference from:
 https://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/reference/javascript.html

Comment: @KevalMehta if I learned anything from all this, is that Odoo documentation cannot be trusted. You loose days of development if you believe it too much :)

Comment: @VishalKhichadiya I didn't forget to put my script into assets, so that's not it. If you have a hello-world working example on this, I'm open to release some of my rep in a form of bounty, or even give you a tip in a form of cryptocurrency. So far nothing worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with [Bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) and I have solution for this [link_to_the_screenshot_of_desired_output](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/_images/qweb.png). It will work fine.

```
Create your js file in /module_name/static/src/js/your_js_file.js and 
add the following code :


   odoo.define('mypetstore.test_js', function (require) {
    "use strict";

     var Widget = require('web.Widget');
     var core = require('web.core');
     var Model = require('web.Model');

     var ProductsWidget = Widget.extend({
         template: "ProductsWidget",
         init: function(parent, products, color) {
         this._super(parent);
         this.products = products;
         this.color = color;
    },
  });

  var HomePage = Widget.extend({

    start: function() {
        var products = new ProductsWidget(
            this, ["cpu", "mouse", "keyboard", "graphic card", 
                  "screen"], "#00FF00");
        products.appendTo(this.$el);
      },    
    });
    core.action_registry.add('ProductsWidget', HomePage); 
   });
```

Create your xml file in /module_name/static/src/xml/your_xml_file.xml and add the following code:

```
   <?xml version="1.0"  encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <templates xml:space="preserve">
       <t t-name="ProductsWidget">
         <div>
            <t t-foreach="widget.products" t-as="product">
               <span class="oe_products_item"
                  t-attf-style="background-color: {{ widget.color 
                 }};">
                <t t-esc="product"/>
                </span>
              <br/>
            </t>
         </div>
        </t>
     </templates>
```

Create your css file in /module_name/static/src/css/your_css_file.css and add the following code:

```
     .oe_products_item {
     display: inline-block;
     padding: 3px;
     margin: 5px;
     border: 1px solid black;
     border-radius: 3px;
     }
```

Create your view's xml file in /module_name/views/your_xml_file_.xml and add the following code :

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <odoo>
      <data>
        <template id="assets_backend" name="give_name" 
           inherit_id="web.assets_backend">
          <xpath expr="." position="inside">
           <script type="text/javascript" 
             src="/module_name/static/src/js/your_js_file_name.js">
           </script>
           <link href="/module_name/static/src/css/your_css_file.css" 
             rel="stylesheet"></link>
           </xpath>
         </template>
         <record id="template_id" model="ir.actions.client">
            <field name="name">ProductsWidget</field>
            <field name="tag">ProductsWidget</field>
        </record>
        <menuitem id="home_page_menu" 
            name="Home Page"
            action="template_id"/>  
       </data>
      </odoo>
```

Add the following codes in *manifest*.py:

```
    'data': [ 
    'views/your_xml_file.xml',
     ],
    'qweb': ['static/src/xml/pet.xml'],
```

Comment: Why not just edit your first answer? I've already marked that one as 'correct'. Seems like you're new here..

Comment: @user568021 That's also the correct program. And I read the comments after answering it. Sorry. Because I'm new to here.